# Podio authentication Server-side flow in iOS 11 browser: auto opening in native app

Tags: oauth, ios11, podio

I am using [Podio API's Server-side authentication flow](https://developers.podio.com/authentication/server_side) in my web application. It it working fine in desktop and mobile browsers except in iOS 11.

As part of OAuth2 flow, when redirected to Podio authorization endpoint (https://podio.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL), Podio iOS app automatically open up, then it shows an error page (screen-shot attached) which says 'Invalid value null: must be url'. So somehow the redirect_uri parameter went missing after the native app redirect.

[image]

Is there anyway to fix this problem?